# Find a basis for $p(1) + p(3) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do i find a basis for
$$\{ p ∈ P_2 | p(1) + p(3) = 0\}$$

I understand how to find a basis for the following

$\{ p ∈ P_2 | p(2) = 0  \text{ and }  p(−1) = 0 \}$. using $(x-2)(x+1)$, but this cannot be done for this question can it? Thanks!

Comment: What are all the polynomials in the set. How can they be generated ?

Comment: I have no idea how to solve p(1) = -p(3). What is the method for solving this other than guessing and checking?

Comment: What is a general polynomial in $P_2$ ?  Write it down, Use the condition now.

Answer (score 1):

The key is use the constraints given to write down some specific equations. Any old element of $P_2$ is of the form $ax^2 + bx+c$, so we can evaluate these guys at $1$ and at $3$. Plugging in, and using the constraint given, we have $(a + b + c) + (9a + 3b + c) = 10 a + 4b + 2c = 0.$ This gives relationships between these values. It is clear that since we have one equation in three variables, two of the variables are free, so that they can be anything. Let's say they are $b$ and $c$. Then these are arbitrary, and $a = \frac{-(4b+2c)}{10}.$

So to provide a basis for this two dimensional space, we make two linearly independent choices, and if they satisfy the relationship, all linear combinations will. So easy choices are $b=1$ and $c=0$, and the other way around. We have $b=1, a = -2/5,$ so one basis vector is $-2/5 x^2 + x,$ and another basis vector is $-1/5x^2 + 1$. These are clearly linearly independent solutions, so we've given the necessary basis.